# Integer division using recursion--and a few other interesting limitations

Tags: java, recursion, division, integer-division, in-place

I am trying to solve a puzzle in Java for my own edification. I am told there *is* a solution by the guy who designed the puzzle, but I'm not able to find it myself.

Here's the puzzle:

> Implement the following method in Java
>
> ```
> /**
>  * Divides a natural number by two.
>  * 
>  * @param n
>  *            The number to be divided
>  * @updates n
>  * @ensures n = floor(n/2)
>  */
> private static void split(NaturalNumber n) {...}
> ```
>
> The NaturalNumber class is simply a class that stores a natural number
>   using a string. ( That is, it can store numbers much larger than
>   `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. )
>
> The class provides these [instance methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRpee.png) and [inherited
>   methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAkrt.png), as well as the `NaturalNumber.isZero()` method, which
>   returns true if the instance's internal string value is `"0"`, false
>   otherwise.
>
> It's worth noting that the `NaturalNumber.divideBy10()` method
>   essentially pops the rightmost digit off the number, returns it as an
>   `int` and updates the instance's internal value.
>
> Do not use static properties on the main class to store values.
>   Similarly, do not write static helper methods.
>
> Do not convert `n` to some other data type and operate on that. Do not use external libraries.
>
> Furthermore, `split()` must be implemented using recursion.

I have the following *near* solution worked out:

```
private static void split(NaturalNumber n) {
  // Initialize local variables.
  String stringBuffer = "";
  int numerator = 0;
  int quotient = 0;
  int remainder = 0;

  int thisDigit = n.divideBy10();

  if (n.isZero()) {
    quotient = thisDigit / 2;
    remainder = thisDigit % 2;
    n.transferFrom(new NaturalNumber2(quotient * 10 + remainder));
  } else {
    split(n);
    numerator = n.divideBy10() * 10 + thisDigit;
    quotient = numerator / 2;
    remainder = numerator % 2;
    if (!n.isZero()) {
      stringBuffer += n.toString();
    }
    stringBuffer += Integer.toString(quotient * 10 + remainder);
    n.transferFrom(new NaturalNumber2(stringBuffer));
  }
}
```

The above simply performs long division. But the last frame in the call stack needlessly appends the remainder of its operation onto the end of the solution.

I have seen solutions to similar problems that recursively subtract two from `n`, counting how many times two must be subtracted for `n` to become zero. But those solutions rely on the method having a return value; this puzzle requires there be no return value.

I can also see how to solve the puzzle using one function call to `split()` and internal loops. But I am told the solution must not rely on loops to operate on `n`.

Does anyone out there have any insight into a solution?

Comment: As well as the problems you've mentioned, your code violates the "Do not convert n to some other data type and operate on that." constraint, since there's a part where you convert n to a string and operate on the string representation.

Comment: I know, right. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the digits of `n` are `a...yz`. If `y` is even, then the digits of `n / 2` are the concatenation of `a...y / 2` and `z / 2`. If `y` is odd, let `Y = y - 1`. Then the digits of `n / 2` are the concatenation of `a...Y / 2` and `1z / 2`.

We can implement this as follows:

```
private static void split(NaturalNumber n) {
    int z = n.divideBy10();
    int y = n.divideBy10();

    if (n.isZero()) {
        // Base case.
        int result = (y * 10 + z) / 2;
        n.multiplyBy10(result / 10);
        n.multiplyBy10(result % 10);
    } else if (y % 2 == 0) {
        n.multiplyBy10(y);
        split(n);
        n.multiplyBy10(z / 2);
    } else {
        n.multiplyBy10(y - 1);
        split(n);
        n.multiplyBy10((10 + z) / 2);
    }
}
```

Incidentally, these method names are awful, and making `NaturalNumber`s mutable is a weird design choice.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. I figured there was some property of numbers I was missing. And about the weirdness of the class and method names--I totally agree.